# miktex+xelatex+win issue on simple eskdtext example (Command \tg already defined)

Tags: xetex, miktex, windows

win,miktex,xelatex - does not work.

linux(fedora),texlive,xelatex - works.

This worked previously for me. Is it my mistake, some package error or miktex issue?

MNWE

```
\documentclass[russian,utf8,simple]{eskdtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xecyr}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{tinos}
\providecommand{\No}{\textnumero}
\begin{document}
sdfsdfsd
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See polyglossia issue. Fixed in v1.52.
https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/465